# When strategy says long Entire chart turns green , short entire chart red

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

[Dont want like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAJ7f.png)Title says it all, [i want like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWWYb.png)

When strategy says long
Entire chart turns green, previous signal should not matter ,
It should not paint zebra , green red green...

Gradient background even better if possible.

Complete chart remains green if position size is greater than 0

I tried few solutions but all give zebra , plot , fill , line.fill ...

Newbie friendly answer would help more...

One of the codes i tried ,

//////////

```
var color bkgcolor = na
var color green = //color.new(color.green,90)
var color red = color.new(color.red,90)

If strategy.position_size > 0 and filter == true 
    bkgcolor := green 
If strategy.position_size < 0 and filter== true 
    bkgcolor:= red 
bgcolor(color= bkgcolor)
```

/////////
Plz help ,

Answer (score 0):

Complete Fix:

```
backcolor= color.new(color.white,100)
if IsLong and PLscreen == true 
    backcolor := color.new(color.green,70)
if IsShort and PLscreen == true 
    backcolor := color.new(color.red,70) 
var tot = 0
tot := bar_index + 1
lowsec =ta.lowest(low,tot)
highsec = ta.highest(high,tot)
p1=plot(highsec,color=color.new(color.green,70))
p2=plot(lowsec,color=color.new(color.red,70))
fill(p1,p2,color=backcolor)
```

Comment: i have edited* uploaded image examples in first line , for explaining better. no this does the zebra effect. not plain.